# Increase or decrease a variable or parameter over a period of time in GAMS

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gams-math

Please how can i increase or decrease the value of a variable or parameter over a period of time generated using an ordered set? 1-24 hours.

I am modelling the charging and discharging of electric vehicles and I need to increase or decrease the State of charge SOC(battery level) after every period (depending on whether it is charging or discharging).

I have tried several methods but it isn't working. Also will it be best to model the battery level as a parameter or variable? I am trying to minimize the cost of customers charging their vehicles while also ensuring they get the maximum charge needed. Here is a snippet of my code.

Objective function is minimize( ∑Cost of charging -∑cost of discharging +∑Cost of unfulfilled charge)

isoc is initial state of charge
fsoc is final or expected state of charge
v1 = vehicle 1
v2 = vehicle 2

```
Set
t 'hours' / 1*10 /
i 'number of vehicles' / v1*v2 /;


Table vehdata(i,*) 'Vehicle characteristics'
at dt isoc fsoc
v1 1 8 4 50
v2 3 6 6 70

Scalar charging_power 'Charging power at station' / 6.6 /;

*Energy cost in dollars per kWh
Parameter energy_cost(t) / 1 0.03, 2 0.028, 3 0.025, 4 0.025, 5 0.026, 6 0.028,
7 0.041, 8 0.051, 9 0.048, 10 0.047 /;


Variable
Icharge(i,t)'charging decision'
Idischarge(i,t)'discharging decision'
z 'total cost of charging'
soc(i,t) 'State of charge'

Binary Variable Icharge, Idischarge;
soc.lo(i,t) = vehdata(i,"isoc");
soc.up(i,t) = vehdata(i,"fsoc");

Equation
costCharging 'define objective function'
soc_const1(i,t) 'Charging or discharging only takes place between arrival and departure'
soc_const2(i,t) 'SOC cannot charge and discharge at same time'
soc_const3(i,t) 'Increase or decrease state of charge after every period';


costCharging.. z =e= sum((i,t), (Icharge(i,t)*energy_cost(t) * charging_power)) -sum((i,t),(Idischarge(i,t)*energy_cost(t) * charging_power)) + sum((i,t), (vehdata(i,"tsoc") - soc(i, t))* energy_cost(t));
soc_const1(i,t).. Icharge(i,t) =e= 0$(vehdata(i,"at")> ord(t) and vehdata(i,"dt")< ord(t));
soc_const2(i,t).. Icharge(i,t) + Idischarge(i,t) =e= 1;
soc_const3(i,t).. soc(i,t) =e= soc(i,t+1) + (Icharge(i,t) * charging_power) - (Idischarge(i,t) * charging_power) ;

Model op_charging / all /;

solve op_charging using mip minimizing z;

display soc.l;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstful your model has some errors based on given. You should add ";" end of table vehdata like "v2 3 6 6 70;". Also, I think you want that the first constraint works on "at" and "dt" for each vehicle. Therefore I change it like:

```
soc_const1(i,t)$(vehdata(i,"at") = ord(t) or vehdata(i,"dt") = ord(t)).. Icharge(i,t) =e= 0;
```

Now you have a working model. But I think that it has logical errors. Therefore you should work on constraints.